# Interactive debugging with Mocha and Atom

Tags: debugging, mocha.js, atom-editor

I'm writing some Mocha tests using the Atom editor, and I'm trying to figure out a way to use an interactive debugger to debug my tests. Any ideas?

I have mocha-test-runner installed, so attaching to whatever process runs that would be ideal.

I'm also currently experiencing https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues/160#issuecomment-405013346 with the same exact stack trace.

I know it's a long shot, but debugging with `console.log` feels kinda archaic. Cheers!